# jquery tab not working after switch theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with my jquery tab when i apply a new theme. Even using the template theme or customize theme, both are not working. My tab only working if i use the ui-lightness theme.

here sample that using ui-lightness theme : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0pt6odov/)

and here the same code but diff theme : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vkq4vjtc/)

html :

```
<div id="tabs">
                  <ul>
                  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <div id="tabs-1">
                    <p>Tab one content.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tabs-2">
                    <p>tab two content.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tabs-3">
                    <p>tab three content.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

script :

```
jQuery(function($)
            {
                $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

            });
```

im still new in jquery and could be wrong somewhere. Please advice me. and 1 more thing, Is it recommended to switch the theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are referencing a wrong jQuery UI css (version 1), try point to a 1.8.16 version like:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vkq4vjtc/2/

Comment: means, if i use the old version of JQuery UI js, so i need to use the same version of theme? can i customize this old theme?

Comment: Yep usually you have to use the same version on library and css. You can customize it, on theme roller (I think). Just a question why you can't update to last jQuery UI?

Comment: is it ok if i just use the latest jquery ui and css? i think i cant  customize the old theme. the theme roller generated the latest version.

Comment: Yes it's ok; I have to check if themeroller is versioned too

Answer (score 0):

You just need update CSS file like
http://jsfiddle.net/vkq4vjtc/1/

with

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: may i know what is this? nothing happen if i add this.